# How to grep exact literal string (no regex)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, grep

Is there a way to `grep` (or use another command) to find exact strings, using NO regex?

For example, if I want to search for (literally):

```
/some/file"that/has'lots\of"invalid"chars/and.triggers$(#2)[*~.old][3].html
```

I don't want to go through and escape every single "escapable". Essentially, I want to pass it through, like I would with `echo`:

```
$ echo "/some/file\"that/has'lots\of\"invalid\"chars/and.triggers$(#2)[*~.old][3].html"
/some/file"that/has'lots\of"invalid"chars/and.triggers$(#2)[*~.old][3].html
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `fgrep`, it's the same as `grep -F` (matches a fixed string).

Comment: Worked perfectly with `fgrep 'preg_replace("/([a-z]+)([A-Z])/"' . -R` (which failed with `grep`).  You will still have to escape `$`, but that's livable.

Comment: `grep -F` seems to be preferred now. "Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated" [fgrep(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fgrep)

Answer (score 20):

Well, you can put the information you want to match, each in a line, and then use `grep`:

```
grep -F -f patterns.txt file.txt
```

Notice the usage of the flag `-F`, which causes `grep` to consider each line of the file *patterns.txt* as a `fixed-string` to be searched in *file.txt*.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the same as `fgrep -f patterns.txt file.txt`. By using a file of patterns, `$` does not need to be escaped.  I ultimately decided to accept the other because it's the least time consuming.